# Is indexing a boolean or enum-like property in Datastore a bad idea for fast writes?

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, data-modeling, database-performance

It is [well documented](https://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/) that fast writing into an entity kind with monotonically increasing values as key or indexed properties is a bad idea for performance.

How about indexing the entities on boolean properties or properties with enum-like values such as Genders?

My guess is indexing on a low-cardinality property will probably suffer from the same problem, because there is no built-in type for such properties. But maybe there is special treatment for boolean properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloud Datastore has optimizations in place for low-cardinality data such as booleans and enums. Each index entry also contains the entity key, which can then allow our underlying Bigtable tablets to efficiently split and hence handle larger load. This works since we don't need to consider sort order for the same value, so having them randomly distributed within their own key space makes no difference to queries, and the entity key is guaranteed to be unique so we avoid collisions.

When we index a value we also add a 'scatter key' property to the end, which is essentially a randomized integer. This scatter key can then be used for query splitting later, allowing things like Cloud Dataflow to efficiently parallelize queries against this dataset.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Just curious, since Datastore has no support for declaring the Enum type, how do you know which property to apply the optimization for? Let me take a guess, again. I can see how this technique can also be applied to any short-text type properties that needs indexing. It may not help there in the extreme case when all the values are unique, but it won't hurt.

Comment: By enum, I meant enum-like as per your question, Yes, this can be applied  anywhere.

Comment: So what you are saying is indexing booleans and enum-like fields (for example: a defined set of strings such as gender) is safe to do because the entity key is used in the underlying Bigtables when splitting the data to handle larger write loads, correct?